# Can I trigger a Azure Function that starts in 5 minutes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I must create a functions that runs 5 min after my activation. Is there a way to do that?
I use a HTTP Trigger

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for Azure Functions and working with triggers?  You should have a few options on triggering a Function after a given amount of time after a program executes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook

Comment: yes but  I don't see any example how to run the function in a given amount of time after executing the http trigger

Answer (score 3):

You can combine your function with a second function to accomplish that. You http function must write a message to a storage queue with a visibilitytimeout (5 min). Then you make an other function that uses that storage queue as input. This will be triggered at the time the message pops up on the queue.

Comment: is there another simplier way to do that on azure. maybe also a alternative to azure functions?

Comment: You can make the HTTP call directly to the queue instead of a function.

Comment: can i do this maybe with azure webjobs?

Comment: You can, but using queue is better scalable.